# Why does my first if statement work, but my else if statement after it doesn't work

Tags: c++

Why does my first if statement work, but my else if statement doesn't? Just hoping someone can see something I may be missing. When I enter in a time between 800 and 1800 the code continues fine, but when I enter in 600 it jumps to my else statement that I entered in an illegal format.

```
if ((time_start >= 800) && (time_start <= 1800))
    {
    cout << "How many minutes did your call last? ";
    cin >> minutes;
    cost = minutes * 0.40;
    cout << setprecision(2) << fixed << cost;
    system("pause");
    keepgoing = false;
} 
else if ((time_start < 800) && (time_start > 1800))
{
    cout << "How many minutes did your call last? ";
    cin >> minutes;
    cost = minutes * 0.25;
    cout << setprecision(2) << fixed << cost;
    system("pause");
    keepgoing = false;
}
```

Comment: Your else can never succeed because time_start would have to be less than 800, and greater than 1800, which is impossible.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I will mark the answers!

Comment: @Mofayew, nah, you can't mark all of them as accepted so you have to choose wisely :P

Comment: @Mofayew I'd rather suspect your question get's closed and deleted because it was really silly, and not much precious for future research.

Comment: The 'correct'  solution would be to use an else *without* the if: as the condition is meant to cover the domain. That is,  there is no integer value that will not match either (corrected) expression.

Comment: I can't delete it sorry it is a silly question... Also I already have an else statement I didn't include here so I can't make the else if statement into just an else. Thank you for your input.

Comment: Then the not shown else is useless; as the else-if shown (when corrected) covers the domain (if the type is an integer or value a non-NaN float). It should be removed to make room for elimination of the second condition which makes the semantics more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a *'logic bug'*: use `||` instead of `&&` in `else if`. It's simply impossible for a number to be less than 800 and greater than 1800 *at the same time*.

Comment: `struct Number { bool operator<(int) const { return true; } bool operator>(int) const { return true; } } time_start;`

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, I was talking about _ordinary_ numbers, not ones implemented as classes/`struct`s since I believe time is represented as a number, not as a class.

Answer (score 1):

`else if ((time_start < 800) && (time_start > 1800))`

It is not possible that a number can be less than 800 and be bigger than 1800. I'm assuming you meant:

`else if ((time_start < 800) || (time_start > 1800))`

Answer (score 0):

As soon as I asked this question I realized my second else if statement should be an or || statement instead of &&.

Answer (score 0):

change

> > else if ((time_start < 800)  (time_start > 1800

to

> > else if ((time_start < 800) || (time_start > 1800

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the code to this, else statement is not needed. Store the value in coeficient variable, that's needed to be defined before

```
// else coef (default value)
float coef = 0.25;
if ((time_start >= 800) && (time_start <= 1800))
{
    coef = 0.40; // if true
}
cout << "How many minutes did your call last? ";
cin >> minutes;
// use coef here and remove duplicate calls
cost = minutes * coef;
cout << setprecision(2) << fixed << cost;
system("pause");
keepgoing = false;
```